# Downloading SSRS Exports in bulk

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that accepts a date parameter.  I need to run this report for every month in the past two years and download in PDF format.

Is there a tool that can automatically pass in a parameter to SSRS and download the export?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own tool or just manually build the links (it's only going to be 24 lines). By adding the [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx) `rs:Format` with a value of `PDF` will instruct the reporting services engine to deliver the report in pdf format.

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF
```

Here's a PowerShell approach [Render SSRS Report with parameters using SOAP in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196523/render-ssrs-report-with-parameters-using-soap-in-powershell) Again, same concept except this has bits in there to save file as an output.